# How to adjust display of midnight commander in kitty?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, terminal, putty, midnight-commander

When I connect to ubuntu from kitty (a putty clone) it looks like this:

[image]

How do I fix the display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the character set on the Window/Translation page of the options dialog to UTF-8.